# Trying to access "id" value with "for. . . of" loop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need some help with my auditTime function. The "for . . of" loop should loop through each element of the div HTML collection with the class name "time-block" and assign the number value of that div's id to the variable blockHour. Then, I want to color-code the div based on how it relates to the reading of the currentHour variable. However, something is not working and I cannot figure it out. Thank you! [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k_g_j/cmzd0v6j/2/)

```js
// jumbotron display 
var currentDay = document.getElementById("currentDay")
currentDay.textContent = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a')
var checkTime = setInterval(() => {
  currentDay.textContent = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a')
}, (1000 * 60));


// setting and getting calendar events 
$(".saveBtn").click(function(event) {
  var eventHour = $(this).siblings(".hour").html()
  var eventText = $(this).siblings("input[name=event-input]").val().trim()
  $("input[name=event-input]").val("");
  var calEventObj = {
    text: eventText,
    hour: eventHour
  }
  saveCalEvent(calEventObj);
  var calEventLi = document.createElement("li")
  calEventLi.textContent = calEventObj.text
  $("#list-" + calEventObj.hour).append(calEventLi);
});

function saveCalEvent(calEventObj) {
  var currentEvents = loadCalEvents();
  currentEvents.push(calEventObj);
  localStorage.setItem("calEventObjects", JSON.stringify(currentEvents))
}

function loadCalEvents() {
  var calEventsArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("calEventObjects"));
  if (!calEventsArr || !Array.isArray(calEventsArr)) return []
  else return calEventsArr;
}
var showCalendar = function() {
  var currentEvents = loadCalEvents();
  for (var item of currentEvents) {
    var calEventLi = document.createElement("li")
    calEventLi.textContent = item.text
    $("#list-" + item.hour).append(calEventLi);
  }
}
showCalendar();

// time block color-coded to indicate past, present, or future
var currentTime = new Date();
var currentHour = currentTime.getHours();

var auditTime = function() {
  for (var block of $(".time-block")) {
    blockHour = parseInt(block.getAttribute("id"))
    if (blockHour === currentHour) {
      $(this).addClass("present")
    } else if (blockHour < currentHour) {
      $(this).addClass("past")
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("future")
    }
  }
}
auditTime()
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
}

textarea {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  resize: none;
  color: #000000;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}

.description {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.time-block {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.row {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  height: 80px;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  ;
}

.hour {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  border-top: 1px dashed #000000;
}

.past {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  color: white;
}

.present {
  background-color: #ff6961;
  color: white;
}

.future {
  background-color: #77dd77;
  color: white;
}

.saveBtn {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #06AED5;
  color: white;
}

.saveBtn i:hover {
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/open-iconic/1.1.1/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />
  <title>Work Day Scheduler</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-3">Work Day Scheduler</h1>
    <p class="lead">A simple calendar app for scheduling your work day</p>
    <p id="currentDay" class="lead"></p>
  </header>
  <div class="container f-flex flex-column">
    <!-- hour blocks -->
    <div class="d-flex flex-row row">
      <div id="9" class="time-block d-flex w-100">
        <h4 class="hour">9AM</h4>
        <ul id="list-9AM" class="event-list d-flex flex-column"></ul>
        <input type="text" name="event-input" class="event-form" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" />
        <button class="saveBtn">
            <i class="oi oi-calendar"></i>
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex fle√x-row row">
      <div id="10" class="time-block d-flex w-100 h-100">
        <h4 class="hour">10AM</h4>
        <ul id="list-10AM" class="event-list"></ul>
        <input type="text" name="event-input" class="event-form" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" />
        <button class="saveBtn">
            <i class="oi oi-calendar"></i>
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row row">
      <div id="11" class="time-block d-flex w-100 h-100">
        <h4 class="hour">11AM</h4>
        <ul id="list-11AM" class="event-list"></ul>
        <input type="text" name="event-input" class="event-form" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" />
        <button class="saveBtn">
            <i class="oi oi-calendar"></i>
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row row">
      <div id="12" class="time-block d-flex w-100 h-100">
        <h4 class="hour">12PM</h4>
        <ul id="list-12PM" class="event-list"></ul>
        <input type="text" name="event-input" class="event-form" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" />
        <button class="saveBtn">
            <i class="oi oi-calendar"></i>
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row row">
      <div id="13" class="time-block d-flex w-100 h-100">
        <h4 class="hour">1PM</h4>
        <ul id="list-1PM" class="event-list"></ul>
        <input type="text" name="event-input" class="event-form" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" />
        <button class="saveBtn">
            <i class="oi oi-calendar"></i>
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row row">
      <div id="14" class="time-block d-flex w-100 h-100">
        <h4 class="hour">2PM</h4>
        <ul id="list-2PM" class="event-list"></ul>
        <input type="text" name="event-input" class="event-form" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" />
        <button class="saveBtn">
            <i class="oi oi-calendar"></i>
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row row">
      <div id="15" class="time-block d-flex w-100 h-100">
        <h4 class="hour">3PM</h4>
        <ul id="list-3PM" class="event-list"></ul>
        <input type="text" name="event-input" class="event-form" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" />
        <button class="saveBtn">
            <i class="oi oi-calendar"></i>
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row row">
      <div id="16" class="time-block d-flex w-100 h-100">
        <h4 class="hour">4PM</h4>
        <ul id="list-4PM" class="event-list"></ul>
        <input type="text" name="event-input" class="event-form" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" />
        <button class="saveBtn">
            <i class="oi oi-calendar"></i>
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row row">
      <div id="17" class="time-block d-flex w-100 h-100">
        <h4 class="hour">5PM</h4>
        <ul id="list-5PM" class="event-list"></ul>
        <input type="text" name="event-input" class="event-form" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" />
        <button class="saveBtn">
            <i class="oi oi-calendar"></i>
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery methods -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery UI -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery UI for mobile -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ui-touch-punch@0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- MomentJS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
  <!-- js script -->
  <script src="./assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: *"Something is not working"* is a virtually meaningless problem statement without more context. What is happening differently than what is expected? Any errors? Note there is far more code here than what is relevant to the specific problem. See [mre]

Comment: If you can provide some more context for the specific issue that you are facing (ie. what you are seeing vs. what you are expecting to see) that will definitely be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the new class with `$(this).addClass("present")` and so on... `$(this)` is not defined. Instead, use `$(block).addClass("present")`

jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/fe56bjks/7/